# Transforming a Stroked CAShapeLayer

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, caanimation, cashapelayer

I have a `CAShapeLayer` which contains a `CGMutablePath` that has a stroke drawn around it. In my app, I transform this `CAShapeLayer` to increase / decrease it's size at certain times. I'm noticing when I transform the `CAShapeLayer`, the `stroke` gets transformed as well. Ideally I'd like to keep the `lineWidth` of the `stroke` at 3 at all times even when the `CAShapeLayers` transformed.

I tried shutting off the stroke before I transformed then readding it afterwards but it didn't work:

```
subLayerShapeLayer.lineWidth = 0;
subLayerShapeLayer.strokeColor = nil;
self.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DScale(self.layer.sublayerTransform, graphicSize.width / self.graphic.size.width, graphicSize.height / self.graphic.size.height, 1);
shapeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1].CGColor;;
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3;
```

Does anyone know how I might be able to accomplish this task? Seems as though it should be able to redraw the stroke after transforming somehow.

Answer (score 3):

Transform the CGPath itself and not its drawn representation (the CAShapeLayer).

Have a close look at [CGPathCreateMutableCopyByTransformingPath - CGPath Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html)

```
CGPathCreateMutableCopyByTransformingPath
```

> Creates a mutable copy of a graphics path transformed by a
>   transformation matrix.

```
CGMutablePathRef CGPathCreateMutableCopyByTransformingPath(
   CGPathRef path,
   const CGAffineTransform *transform
);
```

**Parameters**

`path` The path to copy.

`transform` A pointer to an affine transformation matrix, or NULL if no transformation is needed. If specified, Quartz applies the transformation to all elements of the new path.
Return Value
A new, mutable copy of the specified path transformed by the transform parameter. You are responsible for releasing this object.

Availability
Available in iOS 5.0 and later.
Declared In
CGPath.h

Comment: Thanks for the response. Won't this take away some of the benefits of using a CAShapeLayer if I'm just replacing it's path every time it gets transformed? Wouldn't it be the same as just drawing to the context in drawRect?

Comment: I am sorry but I currently have no better solution for you at hand - I wouldnt know any other way to achieve that effect.